# Simple way of creating dummy variable in R

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I want to know how simply a dummy variables can be created. I found many similar questions on the dummy but either they are based on some external packages or technical.

I have data like this :

```
df <- data.frame(X=rnorm(10,0,1), Y=rnorm(10,0,1))
df$Z <- c(NA, diff(df$X)*diff(df$Y))
```

Z create a new variable within df ie product of change in X and change in Y. 
Now I want to create a dummy variable D in df such that if : Z < 0 then D==1, if Z >0 then D==0.

I tried in this way :

```
df$D <- NA
for(i in 2:10) {
if(df$Z[i] <0 ) {
D[i] ==1
}
if(df$Z[i] >0 ) {
D[i] ==0
}}
```

This is not working. 
I want to know why above code is not working (with easy way of doing this) and how dummy variables can be creating in R without using any external packages with little bit of explanation.

Comment: Try `df$D <- 1L * (df$Z < 1)`

Comment: can you please explain this ?

Comment: There is a typo in my first comment, it is `df$D <- 1L * (df$Z < 0)` actually. `df$Z < 0` will compare each value of the `df$Z` vector to 0, when the condition is met you will `TRUE` and `FALSE` otherwise. You will end up wil a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` but in R (and in general), `TRUE == 1` and `FALSE == 0`, so multiplying my vector of boolean by `1L` is just a trick to turn the final result to a vector of `1` and `0`.

Comment: Thanks @dickoa. I learned something new from this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can create a logical vector by `df$Z < 0` and then coerce it to binary by wrapping with `+`.

```
 df$D <- +(df$Z <0)
```

Or as @BenBolker mentioned, the canonical options would be

```
as.numeric(df$Z < 0)
```

or

```
as.integer(df$Z < 0)
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(42)
Z <- rnorm(1e7)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(akrun= +(Z < 0), etienne = ifelse(Z < 0, 1, 0),
           times= 20L,  unit='relative')
#    Unit: relative
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
#   akrun  1.00000  1.00000 1.000000  1.00000 1.00000 1.000000    20
# etienne 12.20975 10.36044 9.926074 10.66976 9.32328 7.830117    20
```

Comment: If i want to create dummy for X such that for positive X : D==1, and for negative X : D==0, can i use still same code ?

Comment: @Neeraj IN that case just reverse the logic i.e. `+(df$Z>0)`

Comment: Thanks @akrun.  All answers are acceptable here, but i can not accept more than one.

Comment: I accepted that answer because it was upvoted by 3. I am not bias toward ifelse. Your answer is equally acceptable.

Comment: @Neeraj It's okay. After all, `ifelse` might be easier to understand

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks, `as.integer(..)` might be slightly faster.

Answer (score 7):

Try :

```
df$D<-ifelse(df$Z<0,1,0)
df
            X           Y           Z  D
1  -0.1041896 -1.11731404          NA NA
2  -1.4286604  1.42523717 -3.36753491  1
3   0.3931643 -0.05525477 -2.69719691  1
4  -0.2236541  1.64531526 -1.04894297  1
5   1.1725167  0.80063291 -1.17932089  1
6   0.7571427  0.64072381  0.06642209  0
7   0.4929186  1.25125268 -0.16131645  1
8   0.9715885 -0.54755653 -0.86103574  1
9  -0.2962052 -1.37459521  1.04851438  0
10 -1.4838675 -0.85788632 -0.61367565  1
```

The `ifelse`function takes 3 arguments : the condition to evaluate `df$Z<0`, the value if the condition is `TRUE` : 1 and the value if the condition is `FALSE` : 0. The function is vectorized so it works well in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
df$D[df$Z<0]<-1
df$D[df$Z>0]<-0
```

But you should consider the possibility that Z can be 0.